# Sender-Receiver Communication for C++ or Python

Tags: python, c++, unix

I'm working on a project that involves communicating with different devices as they come in and out of range. There isn't necessarily a host as any two devices that come close together should be able to communicate. (Sender and receiver pair isn't necessarily the same nor a pair - it could be a triple).

I'm looking for a library to handle sender & receiver communication that doesn't require being over the same network.

Ideally I'm looking for a library in c++ (or Python) that can listen for any communication within wifi range and respond such messages.

Any such library should be able to work at least on Linux.

Comment: "`communication that doesn't require being over the same network`" confuses me

Comment: Let's say I had a raspberry pi. Somebody running some code should be able to connect with me without having to connect first to the wifi the pi is connected to. The only ip that is known is the raspberry pi's.
Ideally the pi's ip wouldn't have to be known either.